# Rsync syntax to copy specific subfolders

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

Alright so my web server has the following file structure

```
/
    /home
           /home/username
                            /home/username/public_html
                            /home/username/mail
                            /home/username/etc
                            ...
           /home/username2
                            /home/username2/public_html
                            ...
```

So im trying to figure out a way of doing a cronjob that does a rsync wich will only synchronise the public_html folder of the 600 accounts i have. I thought of maybee doing an exclusion list with every other subfolder name there is under the accounts directories but i wasn't sure that was the optimal solution

Is there a way of telling rsync to only sync the content of the public_html folders without having to manually type in the 600 accounts?
Thanks

PS.: My current solution was something amongst the lines of :

```
rsync –vaRu –exclude ‘mail*’ -exclude 'etc*' home root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:home
```

With this solution if any filenames match the directories name they won't be copied over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using three filters:

```
rsync -av --filter="+ /home" \
          --filter="+ /home/*" \ 
          --filter="+ /home/*/public_html" \
          --filter="+ /home/*/public_html/**" \
          --filter="- *" / root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:mirror
```

It is important to add a "+" filter for all the directories in the tree before the public_html and the "**" to include everything behind public_html.

The only drawback is that all the home directories will be created on destination but just as empty dirs.

Comment: Alright i will try this out, this looks good actually, i didnt think of the other way around, instead of exclusions. thanks a lot!

Comment: Well i just did a dryrun and this seems to work flawlessly, rsync really IS an amazing tool